# Joomla!2.5 ACL doesn't show options

Tags: php, joomla2.5, access-control

I'm an amateur when it comes to Joomla, as I've only began developing with this framework last week. As of right now, I'm going through the official Joomla tutorial, as found in their official Wiki. But either I'm doing something wrong, or there's something I've forgotten, or that's not mentioned in said tutorial.

The last step I've gone through was developing the access control list; however, the maintenance buttons are not showing.

Here's the code how I have it so far:

admin/views/helloworld/view.html.php

```
class HelloWorldViewHelloWorld extends JView {
protected $form;
protected $item;
protected $script;
protected $canDo;

public function display($tpl = NULL){
    $this->form = $this->get('Form');
    $this->item = $this->get('Item');
    $this->script = $this->get('Script');
    $this->canDo = HelloWorldHelper::getActions($this->item->id);   
    if(count($errors = $this->get('Errors'))){
        JError::raiseError(500, implode('<br />', $errors));
        return false;
    }
    $this->addToolBar();
    parent::display($tpl);
    $this->setDocument();
}

protected function addToolBar(){
    $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $input->set('hidemainmenu', true);
    $isNew = ($this->item->id == 0);
    JToolBarHelper::title($isNew ? JText::_('COM_HELLOWORLD_MANAGER_HELLOWORLD_NEW') : JText::_('COM_HELLOWORLD_MANAGER_HELLOWORLD_EDIT'), 'helloworld');
    if($isNew){
        if($this->canDo->get('core.create')){
            JToolBarHelper::apply('helloworld.apply', 'JTOOLBAR_APPLY');
            JToolBarHelper::save('helloworld.save', 'JTOOLBAR_SAVE');
            JToolBarHelper::custom('helloworld.save2copy', 'save-new.png', 'save-new_f2.png', 'JTOOLBAR_SAVE_AS_COPY', false);
        }
        JToolBarHelper::cancel('helloworld.cancel', 'JTOOLBAR_CANCEL');
    } else {
        if($this->canDo->get('core.edit')){
            JToolBarHelper::apply('helloworld.apply', 'JTOOLBAR_APPLY');
            JToolBarHelper::save('helloworld.save', 'JTOOLBAR_SAVE');
            if($this->canDo->get('core.create')){
                JToolBarHelper::custom('helloworld.save2copy', 'save-new.png', 'save-new_f2.png', 'JTOOLBAR_SAVE_AND_NEW', false);
            }
        }
        if($this->canDo->get('core.create')){
            JToolBarHelper::custom('helloworld.save2copy', 'save-new.png', 'save-new_f2.png', 'JTOOLBAR_SAVE_AS_COPY', false);
        }
        JToolBarHelper::cancel('helloworld.cancel', 'JTOOLBAR_CLOSE');
    }
}
protected function setDocument(){
    $isNew = ($this->item->id < 1);
    $document = JFactory::getDocument();
    $document->setTitle($isNew ? JText::_('COM_HELLOWORLD_HELLOWORLD_CREATING') : JText::_('COM_HELLOWORLD_HELLOWORLD_EDITING'));
    $document->addScript(JURI::root() . $this->script);
    $document->addScript(JURI::root() . "/administrator/components/com_helloworld/views/helloworld/submitbutton.js");
    JText::script('COM_HELLOWORLD_HELLOWORLD_ERROR_UNACCEPTABLE');
}
}
```

admin/helpers/helloworld.php (part)

```
abstract class HelloWorldHelper {
[...]
public static function getActions($messageId = 0){
    jimport('joomla.access.access');
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    $result = new JObject;
    if(empty($messageId)){
        $assetName = 'com_helloworld';
    } else {
        $assetName = 'com_helloworld.message.' . (int) $messageId;
    }
    $actions = JAccess::getActions('com_helloworld', 'component');
    foreach($actions as $action){
        $result->set($action->name, $user->authorise($action->name, $assetName));
    }
    return $result;
}
}
```

I've tried to debug this using `var_dump($this->canDo)` but I'm getting no response. What am I possibly missing?

---

**Update:** `var_dump`ing `$this->canDo` in views/HelloWorlds/view.html.php returns this:

```
object(JObject)#43 (1) { ["_errors":protected]=> array(0) { } }
```

Here's the call to said function in views/HelloWorlds/view.html.php:

```
function display($tpl = NULL){
    $this->items = $this->get('Items');
    $this->pagination = $this->get('Pagination');
    $this->canDo = HelloWorldHelper::getActions();
    if(count($errors = $this->get('Errors'))){
        JError::raiseError(500, implode('<br />', $errors));
        return false;
    }
    $this->addToolBar($this->pagination->total);
    parent::display($tpl);
    $this->setDocument();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved, and it was a stupid thing I'm ashamed in myself I hadn't realized that. It's just that `admin/access.xml` wasn't described in `helloworld.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you follow [this tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Adding_ACL). Can you please recheck one more time your code and created files? Because I 100% sure that this tutorial's step is correct (did it by myself many times). There is something you are missing or made a little mistake somewhere.

Comment: This is the exact tutorial I'm following. I've double-checked the code numerous times and I can't seem to get it right for some reason.

Is there some kind of registration/tweaking with access options so the buttons show?

Comment: If you log in as Super User no tweaking needed. As far as I can see the View is correct. You wrote that `var_dump($this->canDo)` give nothing. Here what I have dumping it:  `object(JObject)#164 (6) { ["_errors":protected]=> array(0) { } ["core.admin"]=> bool(true) ["core.manage"]=> bool(true) ["core.create"]=> bool(true) ["core.delete"]=> bool(true) ["core.edit"]=> bool(true) }`. May be problem in helper file?

Comment: Edited the main post with the Helper's code.

Comment: Helper is fine. I have the same. But why it is returning nothing both on helloworld and helloworlds views, that is the question. Have you setup admin/access.xml and file also? All actions are there and you can configure them in component's configuration?